# Finish top activity I don't control when switching away from task

Tags: android

In my app, I have an activity (ActivityA) that launches an activity provided by another app (specifically a Chrome Custom Tab) on top of itself in the same task. However, ActivityA needs to communicate with the page loaded in the custom tab in order for it to function. If the user switches to another app and comes back later, there's a good chance the app's process has gotten killed to reclaim resources in the mean time. In this case, the custom tab gets reloaded, but ActivityA is not recreated. As such the tab can't communicate with the app, and doesn't work.

In this case, I'd like to have the custom tab activity finish, re-exposing and recreating ActivityA, which can then launch the custom tab again with the needed communication channel in place.

I can tell when the app is losing focus by listening for the TAB_HIDDEN notification from the custom tab, but I don't know how to clear the tab from the top of the activity stack while the app is in the background. I also don't know of any way to get a notification when the task returns to the foreground (I won't get TAB_SHOWN if ActivityA is currently destroyed) when I could just launch an intent with CLEAR_TOP.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the trick is to add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` flag to the intent before calling `launchUrl`. E.g.,

```
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = …;
customTabsIntent.intent.setFlags(customTabsIntent.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(…);
```

That will cause the custom tab activity to automatically finish as soon as the user navigates away from it, so returning to the app will reshow ActivityA.